# load multiple columns under one column label

Tags: python, pandas

How to load multiple columns under same column label using pandas
I'm trying to load data from csv file like

```
num name  
1 abc def
2 ghi jkl
```

but the name column should have `abc def` in the first row, and `ghi jkl` in second row

I've been loading the space-separated file using

```
data = pd.read_csv(path, delim_whitespace="True")
```

but this considers the `abc` and `def` to be in separate columns